# Unable to hist NodeJs api with this error "Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated."

Tags: node.js, parsing

i wante to host a nodejs api that parse a resume in render website and this is the code

```
//promised-based HTTP client allow to call eden AI API
const axios = require('axios').default;

//initialise file system to access file on computer
const fs = require("fs");

//create mutipart form data parameters form
const FormData = require("form-data");
const form = new FormData();

//add form data parameters to the request
form.append("providers","affinda,hireability")
form.append("file", fs.createReadStream("./Resume-Titouhi-Omar.pdf"));

//configure the request
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.edenai.run/v2/ocr/resume_parser',
    headers:{
        authorization: 'Api key',
        'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form.getBoundary()}`
    },
    data: form
};

//launch the request and print the result
axios.request(options).then((response) =>{
    console.log(response.data);
    const data = JSON.stringify(response.data);
    console.log(data);
});
```

when i hosted the code in the website he show this error

> May 10 09:43:49 PM  ==> Starting service with 'node ResumeParsing.js'
> May 10 09:43:51 PM  (node:52) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403
> May 10 09:43:51 PM      at settle (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:1909:12)
> May 10 09:43:51 PM      at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:2989:11)
> May 10 09:43:51 PM      at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:388:22)
> May 10 09:43:51 PM      at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1336:12)
> May 10 09:43:51 PM      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
> May 10 09:43:51 PM  (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
> May 10 09:43:51 PM  (node:52) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
> May 10 09:43:51 PM  (node:52) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

the code have to return the resume data in json format

Answer (score 0):

in your authorization header, you probably forgot to to add the prefix 'Bearer'. You request headers should look something like this:

```
headers:{
    authorization: `Bearer ${Apikey}`,
    ....
},
```